# Cannot use CoreSphereConsoleBundle because of circular reference detected

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to use CoreSphereConsoleBundle to make running commands easier. The installation was totally painless, but after I was done with it I went to my symfony toolbar and I saw the new icon, I hit it and I got this error:

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Circular reference detected when adding a fallback catalogue for locale "".") ...`

What does this error have to do with CoreSphereConsoleBundle? Why does it show up only when I want to use this bundle? Thanks

Comment: Just an idea: have you cleared the cache? Is the bundle correctly [configured](https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle/blob/master/readme.md)?

Comment: Absolutely, cache's been cleaned many times

Comment: Did you define the [`locale:`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/096c108a2e5db855606c41ab3879b7dd25fc84e4/app/config/parameters.yml.dist#L17) and [`translator:`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/096c108a2e5db855606c41ab3879b7dd25fc84e4/app/config/config.yml#L8) settings?

Comment: Yep: config -> `translator:     { fallback: %locale% }` and parameters.yml -> `locale: en`